# Weighted summation of embeddings in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a sequence of 12 words which I represent using a 12x256 matrix (using word embeddings). Let us refer to these as [image]. I wish to take this as input and output a 1x256 vector. However I don't want to use a (12x256) x 256 dense layer. Instead I want to create the output embedding using a weighted summation of the 12 embeddings

[image]

where the wi s are scalars (thus there is weight sharing).

How can I create trainable wi s in pytorch? I am new and only familiar with the standard modules like nn.Linear.

Comment: Upon more thought, is the solution to use convolution? How though? conv1d or conv2d?

Comment: What do you mean by weighted sum of embeddings? Point of embedding is to get appropriate vector based on it's index (like with word embeddings as you said). What you described is a simple `[words, dimensionality]` matrix multiplied by `[words]` sized vector (I assumed, could be `[words, dimensionality]` as well) and summed along the zero-th dimension. If that's what you want, you can create `wi`s within constructor of custom `torch.nn.Module` by issuing `self.weights = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(words, 1))` inside `__init__` (similarly to what the answer describes).

Answer (score 7):

You can implement this via 1D convolution with kernel_size = 1

```
import torch

batch_size=2

inputs = torch.randn(batch_size, 12, 256)
aggregation_layer = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=12, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1)
weighted_sum = aggregation_layer(inputs)
```

Such convolution will have 12 parameters. Each parameter will be a equal to e_i in formula you provided.

In other words this convolution will ran over dimetion with size 256 and sum it with learnable weights.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for weighted avg:

```
from torch import nn
import torch


class LinearWeightedAvg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs):
        super(LinearWeightedAvg, self).__init__()
        self.weights = nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1)) for i in range(n_inputs)])

    def forward(self, input):
        res = 0
        for emb_idx, emb in enumerate(input):
            res += emb * self.weights[emb_idx]
        return res


example_data = torch.rand(12, 256)
wa_layer = LinearWeightedAvg(12)
res = wa_layer(example_data)
print(res.shape)
```

Answer inspired by a previous answer I received in the pytorch forums:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dense-layer-with-different-inputs-for-each-neuron/47348