# Learnable scalar weight in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, concatenation, embedding, weighted-average

I have two neural networks running in parallel. Each gives a features map of same size say Nx1. Now I want weighted average of these embedding like this *w1 * embed1 + w2 * embed2*. I have tried these [1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiply-feature-map-by-a-learnable-scalar/1520) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568400/weighted-summation-of-embeddings-in-pytorch).But the weights are not updating. Any help would be appreciated. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
class LinearWeightedAvg(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, n_inputs):
        super(LinearWeightedAvg, self).__init__()
        self.weight1 = Variable(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True).cuda()
        self.weight2 = Variable(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True).cuda()

    def forward(self, inp_embed):
        return self.weight1 * inp_embed[0] + self.weight2 * inp_embed[1]

class EmbedBranch(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feat_dim, embedding_dim):
        super(EmbedBranch, self).__init__()
        fc_layer1 = fc_layer
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc_layer1(x)
        return x

class EmbeddingNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args, N):
        super(EmbeddingNetwork, self).__init__()
        embedding_dim = N

        self.embed1 = EmbedBranch(N, N)
        self.embed2 = EmbedBranch(N, N)
        self.comb_branch = LinearWeightedAvg(metric_dim)
        
        self.args = args
        if args.cuda:
            self.cuda()

    def forward(self, emb1, emb2):
        embeds1 = self.text_branch(emb1)
        embeds2 = self.image_branch(emb2)
        combined = self.comb_branch([embeds1, embeds2])
        return combined

    def train_forward(self, embed1, embed2):

        combined = self(embed1, embed2)

embeds = model.train_forward(embed1, embed2)
loss = loss_func(embeds, labels)
running_loss.update(loss.data.item())
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
```

Also I want the weight to be within 0-1 range.

Thanks,

Comment: What pytorch version are you using? `Variable()` has been deprecated since quite a few versions behind the current one.

Comment: I am using PyTorch 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `self.weightx = torch.nn.Parameter(your_inital_tensor)` to register a tensor as a learnable parameter of the model.

Comment: Already tried this but no luck.

`self.weight1 = tf.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)
self.weight2 = tf.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)`

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.3.0/nn.html?highlight=parameter#torch.nn.Parameter), this is exactly what you want. So there is probably another issue. In your snippet you don't show how you set up the optimizer, can you maybe show how you set up the optimizer? Did you really add the parameters of that model to the optimizer?

Comment: Here: 
`optimizer = AdamOptimizer() 
combinedEmbed = model.train_forward(embed1, embed2)
loss = loss_func(combinedEmbed, labels)
running_loss.update(loss.data.item())
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()`

Comment: So this is exactly your second problem: The optimizer has no idea what parameters to optimize. You need to tell it by providing a list (or other collection) of the tensors it should optimize, checkout the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.3.0/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer). Next time please provide a complete [MCVE].